# Does a photo-coupled SSR need a series resistor for the internal LED?

Tags: arduino, led, solid-state-relay

I am trying to control an LCA710 SSR with an Arduino digital output. The data sheet says the control inputs are "CMOS and TTL compatible". It also has a schematic of the internals of the chip, showing an internal LED and photo-sensitive something-or-other (switch, basically).

Do I need to put a resistor in series between the digital out pin of my Arduino and the control pin of this IC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies depending on the SSR.

Really, every photo-coupled device will need *some* sort of current-limiting device, the question is just whether there is a resistor or some similar part built-into the SSR, or whether it needs an external resistor.

---

In this situation, the LCA710 is probably less accurately described as a SSR, and better described as a photo-activated MOSFET. You **will** need to provide your own current limiting.

[image]

In the datasheet, you can see they explicitly specify a maximum `Input Control Current`, as well as the `Input Voltage Drop`. If this were a traditional SSR, they would just provide minimum and maximum voltages.

What the datasheet means when it says `TTL/CMOS Compatible` is simply that the current required to turn the FET on fully is within the sourcing capabilities of most common TTL/CMOS devices. Some optos can require upwards of 20-30 mA to turn on fully, which would prohibit them from being used with most common logic devices without an additional high-current buffer.

It's also worth noting that this is pretty much spelled out explicitly: the datasheet says `Low Drive Power Requirements (TTL/CMOS Compatible)`. The critical part here is the "low drive power" bit.

Comment: The "TTL/COMS Compatible" comment is misleading - I would have assumed this meant the thing could be driven directly by a logic output.  However, careful reading of the datasheet reveals that, as Connor says, the input is a bare IR LED, and does need a current-limiting resistor.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Next time I will know what to look for on the datasheet myself.

Comment: @PeterBennett - It's not in any way misleading, you're just ignoring part of the sentence. If they said `TTL/COMS Compatible` by itself, *that* would be confusing. However, they explicitly point out that they're referring only to required current drive. As a whole sentence, `Low Drive Power Requirements (TTL/CMOS Compatible)` tells me pretty much exactly what they're trying to convey.